# Difference between Library and API

Tags: api

I thought these two are same thing.
Since library has also some defined building blocks and function as the API has and it also responsible for interaction also. If not then please mark difference.

Answer (score 1):

A `library` is a collection of classes / methods you can use via referencing a compiled file. So your application is going to "include" those items and you'll need to take care of updates, deployment, etc.

An `API` is just an interface, so you can interact with other external applications without a direct relationship.